# how much is required to make something tamei?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Do all things that are tamei have to be more than an adasha or just a sheretz? for example is less than an adasha of zera tamei?

Comment: Consider dejargonifying this. Consider also providing background for your statements. Where did you encounter adasha?

Comment: See [Hilkhot Shar Avot HaTum'ot (5:1-2)](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/a505.htm) שכבת זרע--אב מאבות הטומאות...

ב  וכמה שיעורה--לנוגע, בכעדשה; ולרואה, בכל שהוא. To become impure by touching _zera_ one would need the amount of an adasha. To become impure by ejaculating it, any amount would suffice.

Comment: Welcome to MY! As @mevaqesh pointed out, we try to avoid jargon without explaining, and we try to insert sources for any of our statements. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Anonymous!  Consider registering your account.

Answer (score 3):

There is no general rule. Some things need a minimum of a lentil's worth, some a barley's worth, some an olive's worth, etc. You just need to check each case. For example, check out Mishna Ahilot Chapter 2 for various minimum sizes related to corpse-impurity.

Regarding your specific example, yes, the minimum size of semen to impart impurity is a lentil's worth (Rambam Shear 5:2).

Comment: What is "Rambam Shear"?

Comment: @DavidKenner - I think he means [She'ar Avot HaTum'ah](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1525231/jewish/Shear-Avot-haTumah-Chapter-5.htm) by the Rambam.

Comment: @ezra sounds correct. TY. Then it should be 5:1.